# How to get a distinct count based on date

Tags: obiee

I have a requirement to get a distinct count of people we offered a job, problem is since we can offer multiple jobs on potential candidate  , when i write my query  its counting multiple offers. Requirement is to count only the first offer, any subsequent offer should not count. any suggestions on this?

Comment: I'm curious: What does this have to do with OBIEE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` like the following :

```
SELECT a.p_id, b.p_name, c.p_desc, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.date BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(sysdate),-4) + 1) AND 
                                    ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(sysdate)),-1) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but i get this error when i try this :SELECT  distinct count(PINUM),tTYPE FROM  DUMMY

WHERE tTYPE ='PEP'
AND STS_NAME = 'Extended'
AND stNAME ='Offer'
AND EXTENDED_DATE =MIN(XDATE)
AND YYEAR =2016

group by tTYPE